# SqlExecuteCommand Incorrect Syntax Near =

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server, asp.net-mvc-4

I have this method:

```
public int GetPreferredRoomID(String roomCategory)
{
   int RoomId;
   return RoomId = db.Database.ExecuteSqlCommand("SELECT RoomId FROM dbo.Rooms WHERE RoomCategory = " + roomCategory);
}
```

But I get an error which says incorrect syntax near =

Comment: `return db.Database.ExecuteSqlCommand("SELECT RoomId FROM dbo.Rooms WHERE RoomCategory = " + roomCategory);`

Answer (score 3):

You cannot assign a value to a variable and return it in one line. You need two statements. You also have to wrap text columns in apostrophes.

```
RoomId = db.Database.ExecuteSqlCommand("SELECT RoomId FROM dbo.Rooms WHERE RoomCategory = '" + roomCategory + "'"); 
return RoomId;
```

However, that looks as if you are open for [sql-injection](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/cc163917.aspx). Use parametrized queries instead.

Comment: May want to add single quotes around `roomCategory` since it's a string

Answer (score 0):

In SQL statements you need to add single quotes for String values.

the correct way to do this is just add  single quote before and after `roomCategory`

here is the right answer.

```
public int GetPreferredRoomID(String roomCategory)
{
   int RoomId;
   return RoomId = db.Database.ExecuteSqlCommand("SELECT RoomId FROM dbo.Rooms WHERE RoomCategory = '" + roomCategory +"'");
}
```